# Passing properties present in <parent> tag via command line

Tags: maven, maven-3

Folks,

We have one child pom and parent POM we are accessing some of the properties defined in parent pom in child pom.xml

Is there any way we can pass these property from command line or some other way .

Reason is we want to run pom.xml of child independently of parent hence we want to supply parent properties from outside.

e.g property my-project-version is defined in parent pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <relativePath>../main/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>${my-project-version}</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command-line `mvn -Dmy-project-version=1.2.3`. Properties passed via the command-line will override properties defined in the POM.

Comment: It does not work for <parent> tag. It is replacing in other places

Comment: Oh, right. I had forgotten that the parent properties can't be overridden from the command-line.